# make a 4 rectangle equivalent list on android

Tags: android, list, gridview

i want to implement a view like the image attached.

i have already tried to create it by using tablelayout but the problem is the items gather together

i try to use gridview and wrote an adapter to that but the problem still exist and the items don't locate at right position and they all come together

my table layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_page_gride_view_adapter_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_page_values_levels"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_page_gride_view_adapter_text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_page_values_estamina"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_page_gride_view_adapter_text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_page_values_speed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_page_gride_view_adapter_text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_page_values_high_scores"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and what is want is this:

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: you can do it with 3linear layout.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: how should i do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to another answers, i finally find the solution but it's not a global solution and it works just for this example (4 rectangles) and i still don't know how to have a good pattern for for example 6 rectangles or even more.

so i still looking for answer!!! :))

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_page_controller_levels"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main_page_values_levels"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_page_values_controller_font_size"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_page_controller_estamina"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main_page_values_estamina"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_page_values_controller_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_page_controller_speed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main_page_values_speed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_page_values_controller_font_size"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_page_controller_high_scores"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main_page_values_high_scores"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_page_values_controller_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to use weight property into Linearlayout.

 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but it's not like the image! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it with 3 Linear Layouts

**example:**

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation:"vertical"
       android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation:"horizontal"
       android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation:"horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```